# What are the components I would need for an electromagnet with the given specifications?

Tags: batteries, electromagnetism, wire, core, electromagnet

I need to make an electromagnet that exerts at least 5 times its own weight on a ferromagnetic material kept 0.03 m away.

I know that:

**F = [(number of turns × current)2 × magnetic constant(4 × pi × 10-7) × cross sectional area] / 2 × (distance from the object you are trying to attract).**

Based upon this, these are the values I came up with that I think would work. Will it work?

- A battery that delivers 10 amperes
- 200 turns of the wire
- A square core with a side-length of 0.07m.

The wire has to be 200 * 0.28m = 56m long, and the diameter should be 7/200cm (if we use these specifications.)

**What do I want?**

It would be great if someone could guide me and tell me if this would work, and then which components I should get (which battery, wire, and core.)

If you want to modify these numbers, feel free to do them as long as the electromagnet weighs less than 5 times the force it exerts on the ferromagnetic material kept 0.03m away.

Comment: which ferromagnetic material (permeability) ? Which core shape ? or if possible, can you directly specify the reluctance/permeance of the whole setup?

Comment: You've come up with a trial solution. Sketch the configuration. Show your working for how much the copper weighs, and how much the iron weighs. With an air-gap of 6 cms, I don't think 2000AT is going to deliver the magnetic field you need. Why do I say 6 cm? This is where you need to sketch the configuration of the coil, its iron core, the iron return leg, and the thinng it's attractiing

Comment: Does this can help you ? http://production-solution.com/coil-calculator.htm

Comment: @tobalt, yes I will as soon as possible.

Comment: @Neil_UK, I'll send it as soon as possible.

Comment: @Antonio51, thank you, the calculator was helpful.